# How to add space between class and "{" in Less file with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: less, sublimetext2

I'd like to automatically add a space betwen class and "{" symbol. How can I do that?
convert this

```
.class{
     position:relative
}
```

into this

```
.class {
     position:relative
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "automatically"?

Comment: When I push "ctrl + s"

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of correcting existing lines of code, run a global search using `cmd+shift+F` (on Mac), turn "regular expressions" on and enter the following regex:

`(?<!\s)\{`

This will find you all `{` that are not preceded by a space, that you can then replace by `space + {`